# Redux-Form Field is dirty because moment values aren't equal

Tags: momentjs, redux-form

In our application we're getting `initialValues` for a form from an API call that returns something like:

```
{
  myDate: "2000-01-01T00:00:00"
}
```

We then convert that value to a moment and save it to the store and populate `initialValues` from that.  If we then select a new value (say, 2001-01-01, also a moment) and save the form, we read the response back from the api, convert it back to a moment, and throw it back in `initialValues`.  The problem is, now our field is dirty because `moment("2001-01-01") !== moment("2001-01-01")`.

Is our workflow wrong?  Is there a better way to handle managing `initialState`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if `moment("2001-01-01")` does not equal `moment("2001-01-01")` then `redux-form` will always think that the form state has changed if the value for `myDate` is reinitialized, even though the value used to create the `Moment` instance is the same.

The fix is simple: Don't store `moment` objects in the redux store. Instead use a formatted string, like `"2000-01-01T00:00:00"`, or or a number (unix timestamps) to represent datetime information in the redux store. If you need to do operations, like `date1.isBefore(date2)`, you can convert them to `Moment`s temporarily.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping to avoid that but I don't see a better way to handle it.